# New Note Creation After Notes to Lightning Enhanced Notes Conversion

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforce-classic

Is there a setting that can convert notes created through the "Notes and Attachments" related list in classic into Enhanced Notes that will show in the "Notes" related list in lightning?

A similar setting to this would be "Files uploaded to the Attachments related list on records are uploaded as Salesforce Files, not as attachments".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native setting or tool that does the conversion from Note to ContentNote on an ongoing basis when Note records are created. However, users cannot create new standard Note records in Lightning, only in Classic.

The [package](https://github.com/douglascayers/sfdc-convert-notes-to-chatter-notes) that David Reed mentions includes a trigger to do near-real-time conversion of old/standard Note records to new/Lightning ContentNotes, and so is the closest to the native setting that puts Attachments into Files. If you have users that are still using Classic and they forget to only create new Enhanced Notes, then you could use that option.

Answer (score 3):

Doug Ayers has a [free, open-source application](https://github.com/douglascayers/sfdc-convert-notes-to-chatter-notes) available called **Convert Notes to Enhanced Notes**. Its purpose is to do this conversion process from classic Notes (sObject `Note`) to Enhanced Notes (sObject `ContentNote`).

You can install the app in the form of a package or source code.

*I have no affiliation with this application*.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Magic mover app to migrate my 300k+ attachments and notes to files and advanced notes.

The link to app Exchange package is:- [Magic Mover for Notes And Attachments to Lightning Experience](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EHAmyUAH)

You need to consider these points:- There is a daily limit to create a content version in org. Also, it will take considerable time to convert all.